How to improve circle collision logic for large clusters and prevent overlapping
I have a simulation that handles collisions of circles in a 2d space, using standard midpoint-axis overlap separation logic for the physics resolution. For collisions involving less than 3 circles, the overlap is resolved correctly. However, collisions involving many circles are problematic, especially cases with a "cluster" of circles.
For example, consider the circles are gravitating towards a central point. The inner circles will become surrounded by other circles, and the model breaks down quickly. What is left is a never-ending jittery mess, due to every subsequent frame consisting of unresolved overlap.
My understanding of this issue is that the overlaps are only being resolved in isolated cases. Ideally, you could perform one global collision resolution and separate all circles, leaving no overlap anywhere. Some of the solutions I've seen presented (and which I have tried):

multiple iterations of collisions per frame (theoretically, this could be repeated until no overlap is left)
sub-stepping the frame to reduce motion per update and thus the amount of overlap initially

While these solutions help, they are expensive and seem to rely on brute force. But most critically, they don't actually solve the issue.
If there is an answer, I assume it involves looking at the entire map/all entities at once, and then performing an algorithm that maybe starts at the inner-most circle and sweeps outwards.
I should note that I'm using a quadtree to partition the space and detect collisions, but I don't think that would have much bearing on how the collisions are resolved.

Why is there any overlap at all? Just calculate each step whether any overlap would occur, and if so, instead calculate where (along the current trajectory) does the current circle touch the other circle. You can then translate the circle to this exact position, and calculate the new velocity vectors for both circles. Since there's no overlap anymore, there should be no jittering. If there is, just make the collisions inelastic and add some kinetic energy loss so circles trapped in the center quickly lose their energy to bounce around.
Below is my (crudely drawn) illustration of how the delta updates should work-  attempting to move each single in turn, and backing them off as collisions are detected, until there's no collisions. In the worst case, the circle is already contacting another circle in the direction it wants to move, and so it doesn't move at all (but you will update its velocity vector, so it moves next time step).

To find how far to backoff each step, you just project the other circle's center onto your velocity vector and get the displacement vector (labeled V in the image above). Then calculate the current hypotenuse, H1 as the distance between your two circles, and the desired hypotenuse H2 as the desired distance (which is R1 + R2). Use the Pythagorean Theorem to solve for the other leg of the triangle in both cases. The difference between these two is how far you need to back your circle up.
To update each circle's velocity, you'll want to keep two rules in mind:

Law of Conservation of Energy, meaning the total energy in your closed system (in this case, purely kinetic energy) must remain constant.
Law of Conversation of Momentum, meaning the combined momentum in your closed system remains constant.

The formula for kinetic energy is K = m * v^2 / 2, m being mass, v being the magnitude of your velocity vector (your speed). The formula for momentum is p = m * v. You can use these formulas together with some linear algebra to calculate the new velocity vectors, and as mentioned before you can always intentionally lose a bit of kinetic energy to dampen things.

There is overlap because the circles aren't static, all of them are gravitating towards a point. So they always have velocity and there's always unresolved overlap at the end of the frame. That is because, even if you resolve one collision, you haven't checked as to whether that resolution created a new collision. But you make an interesting point about energy, I actually haven't implemented momentum which is why the velocities aren't changing after the collision, I'll see if that fixes the issue.

@6kenzo Even if there's a collision after resolving the first collision, you can just repeat the process, moving the circle less and less along its original trajectory, until you find the first collision

Isn't that the same as the iteration method I mention in my original post? How would that prevent an infinite looping scenario?

@6kenzo just updated my post, hopefully that clarifies things

Your explanation makes sense, but I'm not sure it solves the issue I'm having. I made this picture that might help better show what I'm talking about

@6kenzo I think you may be misunderstanding. You don't move the other circle (in your drawing, "B") to resolve the collision. You only move the current circle ("A"). When complete, "B" and "C" will not (yet) have moved, but "A" will have moved as far as it could before hitting another circle, or not moved at all.
